# Store values from multiple form in $_POST

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to store values from multiple forms in the `$_POST` variable.  The forms are on different pages and from what I can understand from the test I did, when I submit values from a form, they "overwrite" the values that where already in `$_POST.`

Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

Page 1 - form 1

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>

<form method="post" action="page2.php">
First name : <input type="text" name="firstName" required ><br/><br/>
Last name : <input type="text" name="lastName" required ><br/><br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Page 2 - form 2

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>

<form method="post" action="page3.php">
Age : <input type="text" name="age" required ><br/><br/>
City : <input type="text" name="city" required ><br/><br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Page 3 - results

```
<?php 
session_start();

echo $_POST['firstName'].'<br/>';
echo $_POST['lastName'].'<br/>';
echo $_POST['age'].'<br/>';
echo $_POST['city'].'<br/>';
?>
```

The last page shows me only **'age'** and **'city'**.  The values from the first form on page 1 are now undefined.  Here is the an example of the result I get :

```
Notice: Undefined index: firstName on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: lastName on line 5
```

65
   New York

Answer (score 4):

in page2.php
put this

```
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?=$_POST['firstname']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<?=$_POST['lastname']?>">
```

Comment: That is a good idea ! I did not thought of that, thank you very much.  I am still struggling learning PHP, thanks for the tip !

Comment: I just tried it and it did not worked.  This is the result I get :    $_POST['firstname']
$_POST['lastname']
65 
New York

Comment: sorry bro,i forgot to add php tags :)

Comment: if you think my answer helps you then please mark it as answer,so other people can find it easily,thank you and all the best

Comment: Got it, I'll do it.  But in your opinion, what would be the best way to do what I am trying to do.  It's working with the input type hidden but is there a more "correct" way to do it ? By storing the values in $_SESSION, would I also have to use the hidden input ? By the way, sorry my english is not very good.

Comment: do you want to use these firstname,lastname anywhere except these three pages? if yes then session will be better as you can access,if not then hidden fields are better

Comment: Actually, the code I posted was just an example to explain what I was trying to do.  What I want to do is have the first page with a form, a second page with another form and use all the values from both forms on the second page.

Comment: then this is the best way to do it.go as in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use session variables like this:

//Page 1

```
<?php
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['user'] = array();
      $_SESSION['user']['firstName'] = $_POST['firstName'];
      $_SESSION['user']['lastName'] = $_POST['lastName'];
?>
```

//Page 2

```
<?php
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['user']['age'] = $_POST['age'];
      $_SESSION['user']['city'] = $_POST['city'];
?>
```

//Result

```
<?php
          session_start();
          echo $_SESSION['user']['firstName'];
          echo $_SESSION['user']['lastName'];
          echo $_SESSION['user']['city'];
          echo $_SESSION['user']['age'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the code above, you are trying to post the data to two different files.

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
```

This has action page as *page2.php*.

```
<form method="post" action="page3.php">
```

Here you are submitting data to *page3.php*

And you are trying to access

```
echo $_POST['firstName'].'<br/>';
echo $_POST['lastName'].'<br/>';
```

in *page3.php* which you have passed to *page2.php*. Definitely this won't work as you can access the values submitted through a form in the **action** page of the form only.

Comment: That's true, I understand why it's not working now.  What would be the best solution to store values from forms located on different pages and use them on any page ?